# Pacing for run training plan

Tags: running, training, long-distance-running, running-training-plan

So I am working on a half marathon training plan with a doable goal pace, but it will be a healty PR for me.  The plan that I am using has a chart for various paces at distances.  It's the Nike 1/2 marathon training plan that can be found [here.](https://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/en_us/season-2015-su/Running/NikeRunClub/TrainingPlans/NikePlusRunClub_HalfMarathon-Training-Plan7_8_2015.pdf)  The pace chart is on page 8.

Given my current level of fitness using the half marathon goal pace, my mile and 5k times are a bit slow.  The 10K pace, I am unsure about, but what gets me is the recovery pace.  My typically recover pace is about 1 min per mile slower than what they are suggesting.

Is this a big deal?  Should I just run at a pace that keeps me comfortably in "zone 2" heart rate?  Or should I try to pick up my recovery pace?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a big deal if you run slower during recovery but don't let it be too slow. That being said I would try to follow the plan as faithfully as possible, even if the paces are a little difficult at first. After 2-3 weeks you should be more comfortable with the paces.

I would also reconsider your objective a little bit. Usually you set up your plans based on some information about a recent race or your current fitness level and they give you paces and distances to follow. These generic plans are usually designed for the average runner and will make sure you have a positive race by focusing on endurance so you finish the race. They also want you to have enough recovery time so they don't push too much. If you follow such a plan you should be able to complete the distance and hopefully have energy to finish strong. If your training plan is too aggressive, you will not be getting the planned benefits of each run.

With that in mind, a more conservative plan should help you run a better race. As you build endurance you will also improve your speed with the tempo runs and sprints so don't worry about it being too easy.

Good luck and trust the program. If you do all your runs, you will do well in your race.